# Make eshell tab completion behave like Bash

Tags: emacs, eshell

How can I make eshell autocomplete behave like Bash and Emacs in general i.e. it offers a list of choices rather than arbitrary selects one for you?

For example, if I have two directories "Download" and "Downloads", when I type "Down" and hit TAB, I expect another buffer pops up and shows me the choices. But eshell just completes it for me, i.e. if I press TAB, it completes to "Download"; hit TAB again, it changes to "Downloads".

Comment: You're probably getting some interference from your custom code.
Try `emacs -q`: it works.

Comment: I tried `emacs -q` and it didn't work. For example, if I have two directories "Download" and "Downloads", when I type "Down" and hit TAB, I expect another buffer pops up and shows me the choices. But eshell just complete it for me, i.e. if I press TAB, it complete to "Download"; hit TAB again, it changes to "Downloads".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
(add-hook
 'eshell-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (setq pcomplete-cycle-completions nil)))
```

Comment: It didn't work as well. I tried adding it to my init file as well as manually modified in my running Emacs then start a new eshell. Still not produced my desire behaviour.

Comment: You need to set the value of the variable in `eshell-mode-hook` (or use setq-default)

Comment: Normally it would be possible to customize the variable. But EShell seems to change the variable, which makes it necessary to update it in the hook.

Comment: Probably should use `setq-local` rather than `setq`?

Comment: @xuhdev: or do as proposed in the other answers and `(setq eshell-cmpl-cycle-completions nil)`

Answer (score 6):

```
(add-hook
 'eshell-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (setq pcomplete-cycle-completions nil)))
```

and

```
(setq eshell-cmpl-cycle-completions nil)
```

Both do as you ask and show a buffer listing the completions when I run my emacs as 'emacs -q' to avoid my own customizations. This is with emacs 23.3, are you running a much older version?

Also see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellCompletion which is where I first went to check this out.

Steps to try this out:

1. Start emacs using 'emacs -q' as the command -- no other arguments.
2. Change to the *scratch* buffer
3. Paste or type in one of the above code snippets
4. Put your cursor at the end of the snippet and press 'C-e' to execute the code.
5. Start eshell
6. test
7. if neither one works, report back here with your version info and any other relevant details

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that I have to attach to eshell-mode-hook. Things work as expected. I am using the latest Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to have the following line:

```
(setq eshell-cmpl-cycle-completions nil)
```

`eshell-mode` automatically set `pcomplete-cycle-completions` to the value of `eshell-cmpl-cycle-completions` locally.